# Sobre a URL como ela é codificada e parametros POST

Tags: url, post, codificação-de-caracteres

A URL sempre é codificada, como é feita a codificação, o que ela codifica, e qual importância ou necessidade de se codificar uma url?

tenho uma div, que está com quebras de linhas e fica algo impresso como:

1

2

3

em HTML fica:

`1<br/>2<br/>3`

Infelizmente, ao passar por POST, não é codificada ao ponto de receber do outro lado com quebra de linha, eu acabo recebendo assim: 123 ao passar por POST.

Como passar um valor de uma DIV como eu realmente a deixei, com as quebras de linhas no caso?

Já vi, que quando o post ele respeita a quebra de linha, é codificado ficando algo como isso: `mensagem=1%0A2%0A3`..

Comment: Como você passou isso por POST? Imagino que houve JavaScript envolvido, pois não vejo como o conteúdo de uma `div` possa ser passado por POST usando um formulário simples (posso estar enganado). Muito provavelmente o problema aconteceu antes mesmo da requisição ser formada. O que você pretendia que fosse recebido pelo seu servidor? O próprio `1<br/>2<br/>3` ou `1\n2\n3`? (ou ainda `1\r\n2\r\n3`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você submete uma requisição, seja ela GET ou POST, os parâmetros são primeiro codificados usando a [Codificação URL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_por_cento) (por padrão; se você explicitar que quer uma codificação diferente de `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, a forma de codificação é outra). Até onde eu saiba, isso sempre é feito, pelo *browser* mesmo, não sendo necessário você fazer isso manualmente (inclusive tentar fazer manualmente pode te deixar na situação de uma dupla codificação).

O que são codificados são todos os caracteres "não não-reservados". Há um conjunto de caracteres chamados "reservados", que são:

```
!   *   '   (   )   ;   :   @   &   =   +   $   ,   /   ?   #   [   ]
```

Outro conjunto chamado "não-reservados":

```
letras ASCII maiúsculas e minúsculas
dígitos ASCII
-   _   .   ~
```

E o restante dos caracteres Unicode. Tudo o que não está na lista "não-reservados" é codificado.

Não entendo a fundo o protocolo HTTP, mas é fácil supor que a importância da codificação é para que os dados não se misturem com os outros delimitadores do protocolo. Por exemplo, se você quer passar um dado `a&b` como valor pro campo `x`, não dá pra simplesmente passar `x=a&b`, pois senão o `b` ia ser interpretado como um outro campo.

Quanto a seu problema específico, há duas etapas acontecendo aqui, ambas "corretas" mas que podem estar causando um resultado indesejado:

1) Em primeiro lugar o **texto** da `div` está sendo usado, não seu código HTML. Veja a diferença:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("teste");
var obj = {
  innerHTML: el.innerHTML,
  textContent: el.textContent,
  innerText: el.innerText // Não standard
};

document.querySelector("pre").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4)
    .replace(/\</g, "&lt;");
```

```html
<div id="teste">1<br/>2
   
 
  
      <br/>
  
  
  3
</div>
<hr/>
<pre></pre>
```

Observe que:

- O `innerHTML` trouxe tudo: tags e quebras de linha tal como estavam no fonte;
- O `textContent` removeu as tags, só trouxe o texto tal como estava no fonte (o `1` e o `2` ficaram juntos);
- O `innerText`, no Firefox, não trouxe nada... No Chrome, trouxe aquilo mais próximo do que você vê na página: `1\n2 \n3` (de onde veio esse espaço, não faço ideia...). E [pelo que eu li](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1359469/520779), outros *browsers* têm comportamentos ainda mais esdrúxulos, de modo que eu não confiaria nessa propriedade não padronizada...

No fim das contas, de um jeito ou de outro você vai ter que tratar do conteúdo da sua `div` antes de usá-lo. Eu sugiro usar o `innerHTML` (pois é o que mais preserva informação) e retirar/substituir o que está sobrando, de modo a terminar com o texto que você realmente quer passar ao servidor.

2) Em segundo lugar, os dados associados ao campo `mensagem` recebem a Codificação URL. No caso, `1%0A2%0A3` é a forma correta de se codificar `1\n2\n3` (pois o código ASCII de `\n` é `0A` em hexadecimal). Se no seu servidor você não está recebendo isso, o problema deve estar na forma dele decodificar a mensagem, pois a forma do *browser* enviar está correta.

Comment: Eu enviei um conteúdo de uma DIV que estava com quebra de linhas, no POST ela não é passado com quebra de linhas(puchei o texto com innerText), mas ai eu resolvi botar texto com quebras de linhas em uma textarea, ai quando eu peguei o valor dela(jQUERY = `$("textarea").val()`) o texto enviado no POST estava com as quebras de linhas. O que me venho a pensar que, não posso pegar um valor que está formatado em HTML(com <br/> que quebra as linhas) e passar por POST esperando que saia com quebras de linhas, já que o innerText vai me puchar o texto e não as tags que fazem a função `\n` -> <br/> html

Comment: Uma pergunta @mgibsonbr, se eu tenho como quebras de linhas(`<br/>`) em uma div, e pucho o conteudo dela com innerHTML, o que eu substituo a quebra de linha(`<br/>`) para que quando passar por POST venha formatado como tal(`%0A`), eu tentei trocar por `%0A`, mas como você disse, ocorre a dupla codificação, usei `textohtml.replace(/<br\/>,"\n")` esperando que ao passar fosse codificação para `%0A`, mas sem sucesso.. Creio que há alguma forma, já que o textarea passa o texto direitinho, convertendo a quebra de linha dele na hora da codificação para `%0A`. Obrigado pela atenção e tempo!

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus O `innerText`, como falei, não é padronizado, então cada *browser* implementa como quer... Já o `innerHTML` te traz o markup **todo**, de modo que você pode precisar fazer uma "limpeza" nele. Não sei qual a melhor forma, mas primeiro eu eliminaria as quebras de linha *no fonte*, e depois converteria os `br`s para quebras de linha - `textohtml.replace(/\n/g, '').replace(/<br\/?>/g,"\n")` (O `g` no final da regex é pra substituir todas as ocorrências, e não só a primeira). E para eliminar espaços múltiplos e entidades: `textohtml.replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/\&lt\;/g, "<")` etc